# Database design - voting multiple entity types

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

I'm designing a database for a system where user should be able to vote multiple entities. For example user can vote feeds with a rating value and also the users can vote other users. Currently voting is limited to feeds and users but it could be extendible in future with entities like photos, etc..

So, far I've came up with the design like this with 3 tables.

**User**

- id   (PK)
- username
- ....

**Feed**

- id (PK)
- text
- .....

**Vote**

- voter_id   (FK)
- voted_object_id  (FK but could be associated with either Feed or User)
- voted_object_type <----( ENUM('feed', 'user') )
- rating_value

As per this schema, which object is being voted could be determined by the field **voted_object_type** which is an ENUM field that could be either Feed or User which  makes the **voted_object_id** value either Feed Id or User id. 
I want to know how efficient is this approach? And is there anything wrong with this approach or perhaps are there any better way of doing this?

Thanks!